# MYSQL Inner Join speed issue

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have been having mega issues with this query.

It's a file that's run by cron every 24 hours and runs conditional checks against all members in the database.

Apparently it crashes the MYSQL server (takes 2 hours to execute?).

Every table has primary keys set on rows foo_id & foo_uid so the joins are indexed under PRIMARY and as such should be good for speed.

please help, this is killing me.

```
  $members = new WA_MySQLi_RS("members", $alpha, 1);
    $members->setQuery("SELECT
    registration.*,
    child_base_survey.*,
    child_base_scas.*,
    child_base_smqf.*,
    parent_base_survey.*,
    parent_base_ippa.*,
    parent_base_eac.*,
    parent_base_scas.*,
    parent_base_smqf.*,
    parent_base_eval.*,
    user_access_level.*,
    parent_one_month_survey.*,
    parent_one_month_ippa.*,
    parent_one_month_eac.*,
    parent_one_month_eval.*,
    child_three_month_survey.*,
    child_three_month_scas.*,
    child_three_month_smqf.*,
    parent_three_month_survey.*,
    parent_three_month_scas.*,
    parent_three_month_smqf.*,
    parent_three_month_eval.*,
    cron.*
    FROM registration
    INNER JOIN child_base_survey ON registration.rego_parent_uid = child_base_survey.child_base_survey_uid
    INNER JOIN child_base_scas ON child_base_survey.child_base_survey_uid = child_base_scas.child_base_scas_uid
    INNER JOIN child_base_smqf ON child_base_scas.child_base_scas_uid = child_base_smqf.child_base_smqf_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_base_survey ON child_base_smqf.child_base_smqf_uid = parent_base_survey.parent_base_survey_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_base_ippa ON parent_base_survey.parent_base_survey_uid = parent_base_ippa.parent_base_ippa_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_base_eac ON parent_base_ippa.parent_base_ippa_uid = parent_base_eac.parent_base_eac_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_base_scas ON parent_base_eac.parent_base_eac_uid = parent_base_scas.parent_base_scas_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_base_smqf ON parent_base_scas.parent_base_scas_uid = parent_base_smqf.parent_base_smqf_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_base_eval ON parent_base_smqf.parent_base_smqf_uid = parent_base_eval.parent_base_eval_uid
    INNER JOIN user_access_level ON parent_base_eval.parent_base_eval_uid = user_access_level.user_access_level_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_one_month_survey ON user_access_level.user_access_level_uid = parent_one_month_survey.parent_one_month_survey_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_one_month_ippa ON parent_one_month_survey.parent_one_month_survey_uid = parent_one_month_ippa.parent_one_month_ippa_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_one_month_eac ON parent_one_month_ippa.parent_one_month_ippa_uid = parent_one_month_eac.parent_one_month_eac_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_one_month_eval ON parent_one_month_eac.parent_one_month_eac_uid = parent_one_month_eval.parent_one_month_eval_uid
    INNER JOIN child_three_month_survey ON parent_one_month_eval.parent_one_month_eval_uid = child_three_month_survey.child_three_month_survey_uid
    INNER JOIN child_three_month_scas ON child_three_month_survey.child_three_month_survey_uid = child_three_month_scas.child_three_month_scas_uid
    INNER JOIN child_three_month_smqf ON child_three_month_scas.child_three_month_scas_uid = child_three_month_smqf.child_three_month_smqf_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_three_month_survey ON child_three_month_smqf.child_three_month_smqf_uid = parent_three_month_survey.parent_three_month_survey_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_three_month_scas ON parent_three_month_survey.parent_three_month_survey_uid = parent_three_month_scas.parent_three_month_scas_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_three_month_smqf ON parent_three_month_scas.parent_three_month_scas_uid = parent_three_month_smqf.parent_three_month_smqf_uid
    INNER JOIN parent_three_month_eval ON parent_three_month_smqf.parent_three_month_smqf_uid = parent_three_month_eval.parent_three_month_eval_uid
    INNER JOIN cron ON parent_three_month_eval.parent_three_month_eval_uid = cron.cron_uid WHERE registration.rego_parent_uid = ?");
    $members->bindParam("s", "" . ((isset($_SESSION["rego_parent_uid"])) ? $_SESSION["rego_parent_uid"] : "") . "", "-1"); //WAQB_Param1
    $members->execute();
    ?>
```

Comment: would need to see db scehma, sample data, and what you actually need to retrieve.

Comment: annnnnnnnnnnd the explain plan for the query

Comment: A join of 23 tables. Hmmm. What could go wrong with that. I mean, that couldn't possibly create a bloatload of rows that's too big for available temp space. I've got an idea... what if one of those tables was totally empty. That would cut down the number of rows. Significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Run them as separate queries, from a cursory glance, it looks like you are just joining every possible table with data associated with a reference to an id value. Your results are going to be the cross product of every matching row in each table. For N tables, each row in table X will be repeated r0*r1*r2*....rX-1*rX+1*...rN. With the 23 tables there, if each only had 2 rows, you'd have nearly **8.4 million** rows in your results.

Comment: I'm unclear as to how to run them as separate queries!. I need all the data returned as one array so php can check conditions

Comment: UNION comes to mind but there really is not enough details to be sure.

Comment: It makes no sense to return the data as one array, you are getting every row of table1 combined with every row of table2 with every row of table3.... It's like combining a table with 10 colors with a table with 10 shapes and getting a result the gives you results with 100 results of every shape in every color, except that query makes sense. If you're actually looking for that kind of result, you shouldn't need to "chain" your JOINS like that; it looks like you could just join them all directly to registration (though that may or may not help speed).

Comment: @Dagon Yes, that occurred to me while typing the above, but that'd be assuming the tables have near identical structure.

Comment: @Uueerdo random guess - to little information to go on; quite possibly the whole approach is wrong- but who can say

Comment: what I'm ultimately looking for is an array containing all the user data in the database so I can run conditional checks on each user in a php loop. each table has a table_uid which is used to join the table data for each user.

Comment: If you can query for each user separately, why can't you query each table separately?

Comment: takeing it at face value, i would loop one table at a time, not get all the rows from all the table then loop that

Comment: would it make a difference if i INNER JOIN all tables to registration.rego_parent_uid or is INNER JOIN the problem? sorry im getting confused.

Comment: perhaps i need pay pro to look at this issue, anyone interested in making a bit of coin?

email me thewombnal@gmail.com

thanx

Comment: @user994770, It is hard to know which is the problem without a sample of what the tables contain and what you expect your results to look like. Joining to `registration.rego_parent_uid` might help IF joins are actually what you need, but it is highly quationable that joins are even appropriate for what you want.

Comment: Uueerdo: indeed, it is questionable, i think in need some help on this one.

Comment: when you say "run them as separate queries" do you mean like this?

SELECT *
FROM 
registration, child_base_survey, child_base_scas, child_base_smqf
WHERE 
child_base_survey_uid = rego_parent_uid AND child_base_scas_uid = rego_parent_uid AND child_base_smqf_uid = rego_parent_uid
LIMIT 1;

Comment: @user994770 No, I mean running them as separate queries. `SELECT * FROM registration WHERE rego_parent_uid = ?` and `SELECT * FROM child_base_survey WHERE child_base_survey_uid = ?` etc...

Comment: @user994770 If you absolutely must have them as one result set AND they are close enough in format, you might be looking for something more like: `SELECT 'reg' AS source, reg.field1, reg.field2, etc.... FROM registration AS reg WHERE rego_parent_uid = ? UNION ALL SELECT 'cbs' AS source, cbs.field1, cbs.field2, etc.... FROM child_base_survey AS cbs WHERE child_base_survey_uid = ?`